# Unity "All compiler errors have to be fixed before entering play mode" with empty errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 2021.3.11f1 (Need to stay on this version because of school)
All errors are blank and only show time stamp, there are also a lot of empty errors not just one

What I have tried already:
Made a new project
Opened an existing project

Same problem occurs everytime, I have seen at some places I might need to update but I cannot because of school so I need to stay on this version

Comment: Look in the editor.log file and see if there are more details that aren't being shown correctly in the UI.

Comment: @RetiredNinja could not find anything useful in it :/

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" errors? Also you can check if you have any code under `#if` compiler directives or other conditional-compiled code. Such code could be a reason of compile-time-only errors.